# manipulate partial view's content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

With the code below I am trying to update `PartialView`'s HTML.

```
open_Modal_AssignAmendRoles = function (url) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url,//PartialView URL           
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

                var modalhtml = data;


                var result = datafetchfunction("action URL", )

                if (result.compleate == true) {

                    result.data.employeeroles.forEach(function (roletype) {

                        var tagbox = $(modalhtml).find("#tagbox" + roletype.clientroletypeid); 
                        var span = $(modalhtml).find("#rolecontainer" + roletype.clientroletypeid);                        
                        var roletypeid = roletype.clientroletypeid

                        roletype.roles.forEach(function (role) {

                            var roleid = role.FK_ClientRoleID
                            var roledescription = role.ClientRole_Description;
                            var rolecode = role.ClientRole_Code
                            var markup = ""
                            markup += " <li class='taglist' id='" + roleid + "'>"
                            markup += "        <button  onclick='$(this).parent().remove()' class='tagclose'>"
                            markup += "            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span>"
                            markup += "        </button>"
                            markup += "         <a class='assignedrole' href='Javascript:void(0);' onclick='pop_click_fn(this)'"
                            markup += "         role-id='" + roleid + "' role-type-id=" + roletypeid + ""
                            markup += "         data-toggle='popover'  data-trigger='hover' data-content='" + roledescription + "' data-placement='top' >  " + rolecode + "    </a>" 
                            markup += " </li>";                        

                            $(span).append(markup)


                        })




                    })



                    openModal( modalhtml);
                }



            }
        });

    }
```

***Step 1:***

On button click the `open_Modal_AssignAmendRoles()` function is called. Then it goes to the `success()` function.

***Step 2:***

```
var result = datafetchfunction("action URL" )
```

this fetch data as JSON format

***Step 3:***

Then I start some loop, I already create some spans and find them with

```
var span = $(modalhtml).find("#rolecontainer" + roletype.clientroletypeid);
```

***Step 4:***

then I build a markup and assign this

```
$(span).append(markup)
```

and finally, call

```
openModal( modalhtml);
```

But `modalhtml` is not updated as expected, it means `li`s which I created with loop is not added.

Can someone tell me what is the problem and how to solve this?

Comment: I am not sure that this is the problem, but it looks like a typo - `result.compleate`.

Comment: Thanx @Ivan for the edit,now its looks better.